# Notation - brackets

Tags: notation

How should I interpret the square brackets [] in the third formula below?

[image]

Comment: Same meaning as regular brackets (.)...

Comment: It can be easier to follow an equation if it is written with [square brackets], {braces} and (parentheses), so it is obvious what level everything is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this actually has some form of answer:

The square brackets there simply indicate that everything within them is being multiplied by the $\Sigma_{x|y}$ term out the front. They serve the same function as the round brackets $()$ around $y-b$ in the same equation, but since that had already been used, a different set of brackets is typically used to reduce confusion. If a third kind was required, braces $\{\}$ would typically be used next.